# System of inequalities any real numbers

Tags: inequality

Here is a system of inequalities I've been trying to solve, and  nothing so far;
$y>x,$
$1>y,$
$1>x,$
$x>y/2,
x>(2-y)/3,
y>0,
x>0,
1>x+y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "solve". The solution is a triangular region in the plane bounded by the lines $y=2x$, $x+y=1$ and $y=x$. Some of the stated conditions are superfluous, such as $x>0$, $y>0$ and $x<1$ since they are already implied by the other constraints.

Comment: Find such y and x that satisfy those inequalities. What do you mean by triangular region....?

Comment: I mean the triangle formed by these lines. Any point inside the triangle satisfies all the inequalities. There are infinitely many such points.

Comment: But there is no pair that satisfy x>(2-y)/3

Comment: Have you changed the question?

Comment: No i haven't changed

Comment: Ok so if you include $x>\frac {2-y}{3}$ there are no points satisfying all the inequalities